# Replacing elements in a list randomly in Python

Tags: python, list, random, nlp

I have a list of words

`words=['hello', 'test', 'whatever' , 'hello' , 'apple' , 'test','hello',......]`

and I want to randomly replace **half** (can be rounded down/up by one) of the instances of **some** elements in the list (that are stored in another list) like 'test' and 'hello' with the the words reversed i.e I'd want my new list to look  something like:

`['olleh', 'test', 'whatever' , 'hello' , 'apple' , 'tset','olleh',......]`
(here I am working with the words test and hello)

How would I do this?

I know to reverse the words I can simply do
`reversed_words = [i[::-1] for i in words]` 
but I'm more unsure about the randomly selecting half the occurances part.

Comment: You can generate a random list of size len(words) and take half of it ? Then reverse each index of the list that's left.

Comment: You can get a list of indices of words to reverse with "random.sample(len(words),len(words)//2)"

Comment: @MarkLavin it says Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).

Comment: `random.sample(range(0,len(words)),len(words)//2)`, he forgot to add range